# Alternate Image/text position in foreach loop dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel-blade

So I am displaying two blocks of data in a tile format using bootstrap I can have two halves of a row. In this case on the right I have an image, on the left I have a div which displays text and buttons. I intend to have the even rows have the image on the left and odd on the right. So basically an image will always be on top and under text. Alternating in each row the divs will be mirrored.

Using javascript, blade, php or css how could i achieve this effect?

```
@foreach ($offers as $offer)
    <div class="offersNew">
    <div class="row row-equal-height">
        <div class="col-md-6 paddedCol6">
            <div class="inner">
                <h2 class="centered marginTop0">{{ $offer->title or 'No title' }}</h2>
                <h3 class="sub-header centered">{{ $offer->sub_header or '' }}</h3>

                <p class="centered">
                    {{ mb_strimwidth(strip_tags($offer->homepage_description), 0, 200, '...') }}
                </p>

                <div class="callToAction">
                    <center>
                    <a href="/offer/{{ $offer->slug or $offer->id }}">
                        <button class="buttonOne"><p class="sub-header line0 margin1 white smallerText">&nbsp;&nbsp;Let&apos;s Go!&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/offer/{{ $offer->slug or $offer->id }}">
                        <button class="buttonTwo"><p class="sub-header line0 margin1 blue smallerText">Other Offers</p></button>
                    </a>
                    </center>
                </div>

                @if ($offer->countdown == 1)
                    <div class="row countdown" data-timer="{{ $offer->end }}">
                        <h2 class="sub-header centered">
                            <span class="blueText">OFFER END</span>
                            <span class="days">0</span>:
                            <span class="hours">0</span>:
                            <span class="minutes">0</span>:
                            <span id="seconds"></span>
                            <span id="offerEndtime">0</span>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                @endif

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 main-background hidden-sm hidden-xs max400" style="background-image:url('{{ $offer->image or '' }}')">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a count variable and use modulus to alternate.

```
$count = 0;

foreach($offers as $offer){
    if($count % 2 == 0){
        // show variation 1
    }else{
        // show variation 2
    }
    $count++;
}
```